# AudioStreamer and AVAudioRecorder don't work together

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, audiostreamer

I am currently using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer (which works great!) but when I try to stop the playback and completely remove the streamer, my recording fails. I am unable to get something to record in anyway after I start using the streamer the first time.

With the streamer no longer existing, I have no idea what could be causing it to completely ruin recording functionality. Is there anyway that I can get this working? Any input at all would be extremely valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You may have to initialize and configure an Audio Session, or reconfigure the Audio Session type when changing modes (ending the playback streamer, etc.)

Comment: How would something like that work? I feel like it is initialized because it works fine if I do not start the streamer. Do you have to reroute the audio somehow?

Comment: i had an issue trying to use avcapturesession with audio input right after using audioToolkit directly, and this sleep helped me, but this could be specific to my app( because of some race conditions)